# Why I can't open this animation gnuplot file?

Tags: loops, animation, plot, gnuplot

I'm struggling since I want to plot the second and third column of a `.txt` file which contains rows with this format: `#TIME #POS_X #POS_Y #POS_Z`; so what I want is just a 2D animated plot. My goal is to create an animation which shows the trajectory of points (actually they're planet, but that's not relevant for the question).
I don't know a lot about gnuplot animation, but the code I use is really simple, here it is:

```
# define fixed axis-ranges
set xrange [-6e12:6e12]
set yrange [-6e12:6e12]

# filename and n=number of lines of your data 
filedata = 'object1.dat'
n = system(sprintf('cat %s | wc -l', filedata))

do for [j=1:n] {
    set title 'time '.j
    plot 'object1.dat' u 2:3 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
         'object1.dat' u 2:3 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2, \
         'object2.dat' u 2:3 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
         'object2.dat' u 2:3 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2, \
         'object3.dat' u 2:3 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
         'object3.dat' u 2:3 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2,\
         'object4.dat' u 2:3 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
         'object4.dat' u 2:3 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2,\
         'object5.dat' u 2:3 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
         'object5.dat' u 2:3 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2,\
         'object6.dat' u 2:3 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
         'object6.dat' u 2:3 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2,\
         'object7.dat' u 2:3 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
         'object7.dat' u 2:3 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2,\
         'object8.dat' u 2:3 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
         'object8.dat' u 2:3 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2,\
         'object9.dat' u 2:3 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
         'object9.dat' u 2:3 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2

    pause 0.1
}
```

Then I try to execute it in `gnuplot` but the animation does not start in anyway, I also looked for some examples on the internet and the same error occurs...
I tried also to delete the `\` from the rows, but that does not seem to change at all.
I've also changed format from `dat` to `txt` but that neither works.
I compiled this little code (see image) in gnuplot (I have version `Version 5.4 patchlevel 2`) and also from my WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) terminal and I got this kind of error that can't find out how to solve:

[Error Message in WSL terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLyiD.png)

Could anyone give me suggestions on how to fix?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! The error messages show that the input file `object1.dat` can't be found (probably you are in the wrong working directory); the second error looks like there is some deeper problem. Is gnuplot working properly for you? Do you get a window when you simply `plot sin(x)`? If not, then something with your installation is wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Eldrad, I am able to make something simple like `plot sin(x)` but the animation does not start at all; the files `object.dat` are all in the working directory and I can't understand why it does not work, also the plot of every file for each time works, but when dealing with the code of the animation, something is not working...

Comment: Do you still get a "no such file" from cat? If yes, then your `n` is equal 0 and the iteration would go from 1 to 0, which means it stops before the first run.
In general specific details or error messages would be more helpful for us than the general statement "it does not work" – this could mean everything.

Comment: @RickCar in addition to @Eldrad's comment, add a line `print n` before the loop and tell us what the number `n` is.

Comment: Trying to write
`filedata = 'object0.txt'`
`n = system(sprintf('cat %s | wc -l', filedata))`
`print n`
in gnuplot gives a blank line.
So I guess the problem is this part of the code, since it's essential to enter the loop

Comment: @RickCar instead of the system command, try the following lines: `stats 'object1.txt' nooutput` and `n = STATS_records`. This will give you the number of datalines in your file into `n`.

Comment: I get 43800 as value of `n` and the blank graphic of gnuplot, since I get an `invalid command` error at line 15.
This is my line, what is wrong with it?
[image](file:///C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/img1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you test the following code?
This doesn't include external files, so if this works at your site, then there must be something "wrong" with your files.

**Code:**

```
### animated trajectories
reset session

# create some random test data
N = 5
M = 20
set print $Data
    do for [n=1:N] {
        x=rand(0)-0.5
        y=rand(0)-0.5
        do for [m=1:M] {
            print sprintf("%g %g", x=x+rand(0)*0.2-0.1, y=y+rand(0)*0.2-0.1)
        }
        print ""; print ""   # two empty lines
    }
set print

# set terminal gif animate delay 20    # uncomment this line for file output
# set output "SO/SO70198929.gif"       # uncomment this line for file output

set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
set key Left noautotitle

do for [m=0:M-1] {
    plot for [n=0:N-1] $Data u 1:2 index n every ::::m  w l      lc n, \
         for [n=0:N-1]    '' u 1:2 index n every ::m::m w p pt 7 lc n ti sprintf("%g",n+1)
    pause 0.2                          # comment this line for file output
}

# set output                           # uncomment this line for file output
### end of code
```

**Result:** (using `GIF` terminal. (un)comment the necessary lines above)

[image]

Comment: Hi @theozh, this code does work on my gnuplot terminal and produce this animation: as written above I guess the problem is to enter the loop, since the value of `n` is not visible, so I might suspect it is not set to the value I gave to it